# JQuery UI Autocomplete can't process mouse event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hello I have simple JQuery UI Autocomplete realization

```
$("#adrField").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var reqvesturl = "myurl";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: reqvesturl,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.description + " (" + item.itemCount + ")",
                        value: item.description,
                        obj: item
                    };
                }))
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        // this.value
        console.log(ui.item.label);

        var reqvesturl = "myurl");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: reqvesturl,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                addrHelper.showAddresses(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });

    }        
});
```

But I can select data from list box just by keyboard event key down/up and enter, If I try to use mouse I can't select it ? I don't see any JS error or etc. 
Can it be releted to some HTML structure or something other stuff ?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't select"?

Comment: I'm moving mouse over items, but no any action over them. (I am using last version of Jquery and JQ-ui)

Comment: @cleric you want the event to happen when you click it?

Comment: yes, why not. may be it help to understand what is wrong.

Comment: Any chance you can set up a small [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. This is other my script block AC behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Please share the answer here. Other people might use it in the future.